# How to use MariaDB in Docker?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am trying to setup a MariaDB container to use in Docker, but I seem to be doing something wrong. I start by downloading and then running it with this command:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8002:80 --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -v c:/mysql -d mariadb:latest
```

It downloads it a runs the container. Then I try to run this SQL command on it:

```
docker exec -it some-mariadb mysql -p -e 'select * from my_table' my_db
```

And it gives me the usage information for MySql... I don't understand what I am doing wrong? I am doing this on a Windows machine, if that makes a difference.

Comment: There is something wrong with "mysql -p -e 'select * from my_table' my_db", don't you have to pass username & passowrd

Comment: Please see this : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-sql-query-directly-on-the-command-line/

Comment: 80?  Don't you mean 3306?

Comment: Attend the [_Webinar_](https://mariadb.com/resources/webinars) on Docker with MariaDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried with your command and got the following output:

```
$> docker exec -it some-mariadb mysql -p -e 'select * from my_table' my_db
Enter password:
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'my_db'
```

Actually your mariadb is running, and the output error message makes sense. There're two errors in your `docker run` command:

- `-p 127.0.0.1:8002:80`, mariadb is listening on port `3306`, and you can find out in [Dockerfile of Mariadb](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/21eed39fdd34c84ecd83cc077ad3253cfa875c5c/10.1/Dockerfile#L105) that the only port exposed is 3306. I guess what you want is `-p 3306:3306`
- `-v c:/mysql`, you're adding extra volume under container directory `/c:/mysql`, but the data volume for mariadb is `/var/lib/mysql`. If you want to use mysql data on your host, you need `-v <your_host_directory>:/var/lib/mysql`

If you go inside the container `some-mariadb` and try `mysql` cleint, you'll see there's no database called `my_db`:

```
$> docker exec -it some-mariadb bash
root@63154453ff14:/# mysql -u root -pmy-secret-pw
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you need either mount the correct mysql data volume, or init mariadb firstly.

Comment: Does adding a volume allow me to persist the data in my database, even after I remove the container and create a new one?

Comment: Yes, that's what volume is designed for, mariadb will store data in `/var/lib/mysql` inside container, and the directory is a volume, you can mount it to your host using `-v <your_host_dir>:/var/lib/mysql`. More info you can find at https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/